# iphone responsive design incompatibility

Tags: css, responsive

I have a responsive page that shows properly when viewed over a non-apple product, but once visited from an iphone, it becomes completely messed up, and I have no idea what is causing this.

Link to page:

http://glab.000webhostapp.com/businessCard

Here is a screenshot. I honestly have no idea why it'd behave differently on the iphone (and its not only Safari, but even chrome doesn't display it right)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5F4c.jpg

Comment: some screen shots would probably help. As well as a concise summary of your CSS

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] *in the question itself*, **not only on a third-party site**.